# How can I find what toolkits/frame works a specific web app uses?

Tags: javascript

is it possible and how, to find out, which frameworks a specific web application uses?

I'm not interested in reverse engineering or 'copying' an application, in case you are wondering.

What I am after is that when trying to figure out which framework to use I think it would be useful to find a web app that has the similar kind of nature as what you are developing and then look at what tools they are using.

This information is not often disclosed for many app AFAIK.

So are there any tell tale signs in the page source as reveal  by browser 'Show Page Source' or JavaScript debugger.

Comment: Indeed, brilliant, just what the doctor ordered, put it up as an answer!

Comment: No need. This will just be closed as a duplicate as soon as it gets the relevant votes.

Comment: Ok. I need to improve my google skills ;) and SO needs to improve its algorithm that suggest 'similar questions' ;) ;)